# Speed - Copy bitmap data into array or work with it directly?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, image-processing, bitmap

I'm using a `LockedBitmap` class that simplifies working with bitmap data in C#. Currently it is copying the data into a local `byte[]` array which is then accessed by its class methods to get/set pixel color values.

Is this faster or better than accessing the locked bitmap data directly via the pointer? Is a copy needed at all?

**Edit:** I'm not asking if its possible to directly work with bitmap data, I work with this everyday. I'm just asking for a comparison between the 2 methods and if its necessary at all to copy pixel data.

---

Copying pixel data into a temp array:

```
// create byte array to copy pixel values
int step = Depth / 8;
Pixels = new byte[PixelCount * step];
Iptr = bitmapData.Scan0;

// Copy data from pointer to array
Marshal.Copy(Iptr, Pixels, 0, Pixels.Length);
```

Directly reading pixel values:

```
byte* p = (byte*)(void*)bmData.Scan0.ToPointer();
int ws = bmData.Stride;
byte* row = &p[i * ws];
byte Gcolor = row[j];
byte Bcolor = row[j + 1];
byte Rcolor = row[j + 2];
```

Comment: You have both versions, why don't you measure them?

Comment: I'm also asking if there are long term differences, eg. array being faster to work with than the bitmap memory or something thats beyond the code snippet I gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this faster or better than accessing the locked bitmap data
>   directly via the pointer?

No. It requires an additional copy operation, and then another operation to copy the processed values back to the bitmap.

> Is a copy needed at all?

Only in an environment where `unsafe` code is undesired or unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely operate directly on the bitmap data without copying it. Here is some code that I used to pull in a customer 16bpp gray scale format into a displayable bitmap:

```
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmOut.Width, bmOut.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
        bmOut.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        bmOut.PixelFormat);
    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    Byte[] bytes;

    bytes = rawIn.ReadBytes(framesize);

    for (int x = 0; x < bytes.Length; x += 2)
    {
        short[] rgb = new short[3];
        int value = bytes[x + 1] * 256 + bytes[x];
        //value = value / 32;
        value = iMax * (value - iMin) / (iMax - iMin);

        if (value < iMin)
        {
            value = iMin;
        }
        else if (value > iMax)
        {
            value = iMax;
        }

        value = 65536 * (value - iMin) / (iMax - iMin);

        rgb[0] = rgb[1] = rgb[2] = (short)(value);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgb, 0, ptr + (x) * 3, 3);

    }
    bmOut.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

The key is the `LockBits` and `UnlockBits`

As a quick explanation, I'm reading 16bpp from the file into `bytes`, reconstructing the 16 bits into `value`. Then, using externally supplied `iMin` and `iMax` scaling to get the shading right. Then taking that single `value` and constructing the RGB and using the `Marshal.Copy` to put it into the bitmap.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer, but I'm basically asking for a comparison between the copy bytes method and the direct method. I know exactly how to work with both methods.

Comment: @Geotarget I misunderstood your question then, because you said "Is a copy needed at all?". A copy isn't needed, and in fact, without doing a performance test, it has to be faster in the vast majority of situations to interact directly with the memory than it is to copy everything out, manipulate it, and copy it back. The exception to this is if multiple threads need to access the memory, then locking it for potentially long periods of time could negatively affect timing. But as far as the Lock/Unlock bits, you are directly accessing memory then, using a pointer, it doesn't get much faster.