# How To Identify a Jpeg image is Bi-Tonal

Tags: c#, image

I'm new to using images in c#.

I done this :

```
private bool IsBitonal(string FilePath)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(FilePath);
    return (bitmap.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)   
}
```

this is work with .png files but not work with .jpeg files can any one help me?

is there any solution to find image is bitonal or not?

i used Loding graphics thing its also not work with me.

```
 private bool IsBitonal(string filePath)
 {
        bool isBitonal = false;
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filePath);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isBitonal = true;
        }
        return isBitonal;
  }
```

Yeah I got Solution From  [Tomaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1821029/tomasz) Answer

Here is My ANswer in C#:

```
public bool IsBitonal(Bitmap YourCurrentBitmap)
    {
        Color c;
        long Eadges = 0;
        long Others = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < YourCurrentBitmap.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < YourCurrentBitmap.Height; j++)
            {
                c = YourCurrentBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                if (!(c.R == c.G && c.G == c.B)) return false;

                if (c.R <= 16||c.R >= 255-16)
                    Eadges++;
                else
                    Others++;
            }
        }
         double proportion = Eadges / (double)Others;
        // here is estimation based on you requirement you can change
         return proportion > 10;;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPEG images are by definition defined in colours. Even a bitonal image saved in JPEG and reread will never be bitonal due to compression artefacts.

All you can do is to make some estimation, e.g. create a histogram and manually check (with some error) if values are distributed along it's edges or not.

Edit:

This should be a fast method of calculating histograms. If you prefer a (much) slower, but simpler way, you can instead use getPixel() for each pixel in the picture.

Based on:
http://aforge.googlecode.com/svn/tags/AForge-1.5.0/Sources/Imaging/ImageStatisticsHSL.cs

```
    private int[] getHistogram( BitmapData imageData )
    {
        int width = imageData.Width;
        int height = imageData.Height;
        int offset = imageData.Stride - width * 3;

        int[] l = new int[256];

        unsafe
        {
            byte * p = (byte *) imageData.Scan0.ToPointer( );

            // for each line
            for ( int y = 0; y < height; y++ )
            {
                // for each pixel
                for ( int x = 0; x < width; x++, p += 3 )
                {
                    int bright = p[RGB.R] + p[RGB.G] + p[RGB.B];
                    bright /= 3;

                    l[bright]++;
                }
                p += offset;
            }
        }

        return l; 
    }
```

I can't test it at the moment, but it should be easy for you to understand the idea. You can always use liblary like AForge.NJET to generate the histogram.

Once you have the histogram, you should check if all values are located around two points.

```
int[] hist = getHistogram(imageData);
```

`hist[n]` is a number of pixels with brightness 'n' (in range from 0 to 255)

For an ideal image, all pixels would be either white or black, therefore hist[0] and hist[255] would be set, and all other values would be zero.
Instead, all values will be distributed around 0 and 255. You can e.g. calculate a proportion of black and white pixels to other pixels.

```
int eadges = 0; // black, white or very close to black/white
int others = 0;

for(int i =0; i<hist.length; i++)
{
   if(i < 16 || i > 255-16) eadges += hist[i];
   else others += hist[i];     
}

double proportion = eadges/(double)others;
return proportion > 10;
```

16 and 10 are just examples - you can pick other numbers for different detection precision.

If you'd like to, you should be able to easily find more information about histograms and other methods of calculating it. Have a look at Google Image results for histograms first.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do the estimation. i don has any idea about histogram and how to find distributed edges values

Comment: @Tomasz Using a histogram is a nice workaround indeed. Note that there is also an intermediate solution between GetPixels() and Scan0.ToPointer() that doesn't rely on unsafe code, while retaining good performance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14834760/1314667

Comment: Thank you :). I do the same thing. but this one is use full for me  "return proportion > 10;" to differentiate grey scale and bi-tonal.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to PNG images, a JPEG image cannot be bi-tonal, due to the way it encodes color information. You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

I guess you could count the number of different colors in the picture to find out if it's bitonal or not, but JPEG artifacts (i.e. color bleeding around the edges) would give incorrect results.

Comment: if i count no of colors the grey scale images are exists also has less colors. can you differentiate colors rages how cal i get?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way: try to convert you image to PNG, then run your code.

Edit: Loading as Graphics should do the trick, isn't it?

Comment: Saving the image as a PNG doesn't guarantee that it will use the most optimal bit depth, does it? Besides, a JPEG image can hardly have only 2 colors due to compression artifacts.

Comment: i also done loading graphics thing its also not give correctresults